# Generate Variable Inside Loop Dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to generate a variable inside a loop using `mutate`. This variable should simply be the concatenate of the word `period` and the loop iteration number `i`.

Unfortunately the following code generates the variable `p` instead of `period1`, `period2`, and so on.

Does anyone know how can I get the name as `period1` instead of simply `p`?

The expected outcome is the following:

```
Fr1 <- data.frame (v1  = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  v2 = c("1", "2", "a"),
                  v3 = c("2", "4", "c"),
                  period1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
)

Fr2 <- data.frame (v1  = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   v2 = c("1", "2", "a"),
                   v3 = c("2", "4", "c"),
                   period2 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
)
```

```
countries <- c("Fr", "Be", "De")
df <- data.frame (v1  = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  v2 = c("1", "2", "a"),
                  v3 = c("2", "4", "c")
)

for(c in countries) {
  for(i in 1:6) {
     p <- paste0("period", i)  
     new <- "Yes"
     a <- df %>%
       mutate(p = new)
     assign(paste0(c,i), a)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the *purpose* of your code simply to generate all possible combinations of country and period?  If so, `expand` or `expand_grid` may be a more concise, efficient and understandable option.

Comment: @Limey, thank a lot for your answer. Unfortunately this is part of a bigger code and the purpose of the code is not simply to generate all possible combinations of country and period...

Comment: I understand this is part of a bigger peice of code, but you are asking a question about this *specific* piece of code.  What is the purpose of *this* piece of code?

Comment: @Limey, the purpose of this piece of code is to generate one data frame per period for each country and add one variable in each data frame labelled after the period. For example, for Fr the code generates Fr1, Fr2, Fr3, Fr4, Fr5, Fr6. Inside Fr1 I want one variable labelled period1 with value Yes, inside Fr2, I want one variable labelled period2 with value Yes and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this -

```
library(tidyverse)

countries <- c("Fr", "Be", "De")
df <- data.frame (v1  = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  v2 = c("1", "2", "a"),
                  v3 = c("2", "4", "c")
)

for(c in countries) {
  for(i in 1:6) {
    p <- paste0("period", i)  
    new <- "Yes"
    a <- df %>%  mutate(!!p := new)
    assign(paste0(c,i), a)  
  }
}
```

However, it is not a good practice to create so many dataframes in global environment, use lists instead.

Something like this -

```
pmap(expand_grid(countries, n), function(...) {
  df %>% mutate(!!paste0("period", ..2) := 'new')
})
```